# Цикл for и деление на массивы командой split

Tags: java, split

есть табличка `html`, она может быть разной длины:

```
 <tr class="itemBlock"> 
  <td> 44-46
  <td>170-176  
  <td> <b> ожидается

 <tr class="itemBlock"> 
  <td> 44-46
  <td>182-188  
  <td> <b> ожидается
```

Решила вопрос немного по другому, но все-таки при помощи `split`, может кому-то пригодится) насчет грамотности кода не знаю, но все отлично работает)

```
int i, x;          
String [] arraytr=tab1.split("<tr class=\"itemBlock\">");
for (i=0;i<arraytr.length;i++){
   String [] arraytd=arraytr[i].split("<td>");
    for (x=1;x<arraytd.length;x++){
        String [] arrayb=arraytd[3].split("<b>");
        razmer =arraytd[1]+"/"+(arraytd[2]);
        razmer1=razmer.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
        nalichie = arrayb[1];
      }
   System.out.println("Размер" + razmer1);
   System.out.println("Наличие" + nalichie);
}
```

Comment: `а вот как вывести, например, первый столбец не через цикл,` - в смысле значение в первой ячейке какой-либо строки? или значение первой ячейки каждой строки? непонятно. И да. В таком случае лучше использовать не `split`, а, например `jsoup`

Comment: Что значит "теряется"? `String [] arraytd=arraytr[i].split("<td>");System.out.println(arraytd[1]);` вообще ничего не выводит?

Comment: в вопрос добавила картинку, нужно, чтоб выводилось 44-46 два раза, а так как `System.out.println(arraytd[1])` только в цикле работает, он до 8 раз выводит, если выношу за пределы, то java не понимает, что вообще такое arraytd

Comment: Вы ведь за пределы второго цикла выводите, а не за пределы обоих? https://pastebin.com/43MaTweR

Comment: если выношу во внешний цикл ошибка java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Ох, я всегда сплитом парсю) Практично!